# Consider the arithmetic progression ...

Tags: sequences-and-series

I get the idea of arithmetic progression but the "z" is confusing me a little here.

$a_1 = 3$, $a_2 = 3 + z$, $a_3 = 3 + 2z$, ...

1. The 7th Element $a_7$.
2. The sum of the first 110 elements.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has the from of $a_n=3+(n-1)z$

so what is $a_7$? it is just   $3+(7-1)z=3+6z$

To find the sum of the first 110 elements we use the equation.

$S_n=n(a_1+a_n)/2$

so  the sum , S110 is $S=110(3+(3+109z))/2$

Comment: Is the whole lot divided by 2? e.g (110(3+(3+109z)))/2 or is it 110 multiplied by (3+(3+109z))/2? Thanks

Comment: Everything over two

Answer (score 1):

Each term in the arithemtic progression is given by the formula:

$$a_n = a_0 + (n-1)d$$

The sum of the first $n$ terms in th sequence is:

$$S = \frac 12 \left(2a_0 + (n-1)d\right)$$